# How do I do atomic update using Bookshelf.js model?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

For example, if I wanted to do something like the following in MySQL query:

```
update foo set bar = bar + ?;
```

How would I achieve this using Bookshelf.js model?

Comment: How did you do this in the end? Looking to do the exact same, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by atomic, perhaps transactions? You can do that in bookshelf, there's a whole section about it: http://bookshelfjs.org/#Bookshelf-transaction

However, if you're just trying to update a field, you can do that easily as follows:

```
var idStationIWantToUpdate = 1;
new Station({'id': idStationIWantToUpdate}).save({
    route_name: 'my updated route name'
}).then(function(station) {
    res.json(station.toJSON());
});
```

The important part is that you instantiate a model with the corresponding ID, then when you call `save`, it automatically updates the existing record.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get this to work as I expect it, but there's an `increment` method in the knex query builder library (http://knexjs.org/#Builder-increment) which is the underlying engine for this functionality in bookshelf.js

What I ended up doing was:

```
foo.forge().save({bar:bookshelf.knex.raw('bar + 1')},{method:"update"});
```